# How to prepend string to a managed string in c++?

Tags: c++

on the last line of code i try to add 'a,' to my string which gives the Warning: Multicharacter character literal (potential portability problem) in "main.cpp", Line: 30, Col: 35

```
ManagedString accelerometerVectorsString = "";


vector<int> accelerometerVectors;

accelerometerVectors.push_back(uBit.accelerometer.getX());
accelerometerVectors.push_back(uBit.accelerometer.getY());
accelerometerVectors.push_back(uBit.accelerometer.getZ());
for (int i = 0; i < accelerometerVectors.size(); ++i)
{
    accelerometerVectorsString = accelerometerVectorsString + (ManagedString)accelerometerVectors[i] + ' ';
}
accelerometerVectorsString = 'a,' + accelerometerVectorsString;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'a,'` is not a character literal as the use of single quotes would indicate. It is a multi character literal, so you want double quotes; `"a,"`.